# Degree of Galois extension of a real subfield $F$ contained in a radical extension, $F(\sqrt[n]{a})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $K=F(\sqrt[n]{a})$, then any Galois extension of $F$ contained in $K$ must have degree less than 3.

How do i go about proving this claim? I have considered the galois extension $K(\zeta_n)$ over $F$, but don't know how to proceed. If I can somehow show that all the normal subgroups of $Gal(K(\zeta_n)/F)$ have order 1 or 2, then I will be done, but again don't see how that might be true.

Comment: Gal(K/F) doesn't necessarily exist, for example $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois so the Galois group won't help you here. I think the intuition should be  looking at why $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})/\mathbb{Q}$  is not Galois, and that should give you the tools to create a proof.

Comment: @SheelStueber, you are right. I meant $K(\zeta_n)$ not just $K$

Comment: I think you also need $x^n-a$ to be irreducible over $F$ (probably). I also think there is a theorem in field theory about all the intermediate subfields of $K(\zeta_n)$ are either roots of unity or of the form $F(a^{\frac{1}{d}})$ or some compositum. Do you know this?